# Determine the nature of the series $\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{a(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+n-1)}{n!\cdot n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine $a\in\mathbb{R_+}$ such that the series $\sum_{n>0} \frac{a(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+n-1)}{n!\cdot n^2}$ is convergent.

I've done a couple of observations but nothing more. I just don't know how to determine this.

The ratio test fails as $\frac{a+n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2} \to 1,\,\, \forall a$

The comparison test is hard to use here as I can't seem to find a convergent upper bound for the series, nor a divergent lower bound.

Perhaps the farthest I've gone is as to notice that:
$P = a(a+1)(a+2)\dots(a+n-1) \in \mathbb{Z_n}[a], \\
P = c_n\cdot a^n + c_{n-1}\cdot a^{n-1} + \dots + c_1\cdot a \\
c_n = 1, \hspace{1mm} c_{n-1} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}, \hspace{1mm} c_1 = (n-1)! \\
c_i = o(c_{i-1}), \hspace{1mm} i=\overline{2,n} \\
c_1 = o(n!) \implies c_i = o(n!)$

So, for $a \leq 1$, $\frac{P}{n!} \to 0$, so the sequence converges to $0$. But for $a > 1$, $\frac{P}{a^n\cdot n!} \to 0$ while $\frac{a^n}{n^2} \to \infty$, so I can't find the limit this way.

At least I know that the sequence doesn't fail the divergence test for $a \leq 1$. But I really don't know how to continue.

Comment: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryterium_Gaussa

Comment: $n>0$ not $n\ge 0$

Comment: **Hint** Raabe-Duhamel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio of  successive terms is
$$
\frac{{n + 1}}{{a + n}}\frac{{(n + 1)^2 }}{{n^2 }} = 1 + \frac{{3 - a}}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right).
$$
You can use the Gauss test to conclude.

Comment: Just now finish same.. (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Express the sum and as

$$\frac{(a+n-1)!}{(a-1)! n! n^2}$$

Use Stirling’s approximation to find that the term behaves, as $n \to \infty$, like

$$\frac1{(a-1)!} e^{-(a-1)} \left ( 1 + \frac{a-1}{n} \right )^{n+1/2} \frac1{n^2} (a+n-1)^{a-1} $$

Which is approximately, in this limit,

$$\frac1{(a-1)!} n^{a-3} \left ( 1+ \frac{a-1}{n} \right )^{a-1} $$

Clearly, by comparison, the series converges when $a < 2$.